# Changing blog domain name

Tags: subdomains, domain-mapping

I've looked at a few questions that I **seem** to be duplicating.  But their symptoms aren't exactly the same as mine, and their fixes don't work.

I had two blogs as subdomains of Groleau.Site

I thought I had both set up similarly.

The registrar for .Site raised the price too high, so I changed to Groleau.Email.

One blog is working fine with the new domain, but the other is still generating "Groleau.Site" URIs, which means none of the links on any page work, including the header link to the CSS.

I dumped the entire database, changed all occurrences of Groleau.Site to Groleau.Email and reloaded it.  Still getting Groleau.Site links.

I used find to locate all occurrences of the old name in any file on the website,

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il Groleau.Site {} \;
```

to verify that all the instances needed to be changed.  They did (and all were in supercache files) so I changed them with

```
perl -CSD -p -I -e 's^Groleau.Site^Groleau.Email^g;' $(!!)
```

Still no good.

Don't know what to do now.  I thought I originally did the same thing on both sites to make the change, but apparently not.

UPDATE: There must be some sort of caching in the webserver outside of my site (no, it's not in my browser) because after an hour of posting, it is working properly.

Comment: You say you used "find" to locate all occurrences.  Can you please elaborate on what you did?  That will help me give you a better answer.

Comment: Is this WordPress related quest @WGroleau ?

Comment: @prosti: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @WGroleau, I am asking if you are doing the actions on WordPress installation or somewhere else? I am not sure you mentioned this.

Comment: If it was on blogspot, I wouldn't be asking in a Wordpress site.  But anyway, it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually making changes to the WP tables, I use the "WP Clone" plugin. It saves the entire blog to a zip file, then you Restore that on the new site (using WP Clone). The restore process makes any needed changes to the domain names/links/whatever, so the new site just works.

You will log in to the new site with your old site's credentials, but all users, media, posts, themes, plugins, etc will work just fine on the new site.

You'll find the plugin here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ . I've used it several times, and it Just Works.

(Note, no affiliation with the WP Clone guys other than a satisfied user.)

Comment: problem is, the "new site" is a change in domain name, and it was already done.  I did not ask how to move a site, rather how to repair a site that was broken by moving.  And apparently what I tried that didn't work immediately was sufficient after time for a cache on the server to expire.